# Converting and manipulation tf data image dataset straight from a folder

Tags: image, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to load a dataset from a local folder and use it as a tf data dataset. The folder structure is :

```
   ../dataset/
      class_0/
      class_1/
```

where class 0 sub-fodler contains all images with class 0 and class 1 all with class 1.
To achieve this my code is :

```
images = image_dataset_from_directory('../dataset/',
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             batch_size=32,
                                             image_size=(1080,1920))
```

all images are of size `(1080,1920,3)` or `(1920,1080,3)`

I am trying to show an image using:

```
for image, labels in images.take(1):

      img = image[0].numpy() # take first image of batch
      print(img.shape)
      img = Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB')
      img.save('my.png')
      img.show()
```

which prints image shape= `(1080, 1920, 3)`

However the image showed by PIL is distrorted and seems like random noise.

Any idea about what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with floating point numbers for Pillow

In your converting function, you have `img = Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB')`.

Changing this to `img = Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')` should solve this issue.